# SPSS error 4163, import file but columns definition makes DATA LIST syntax line too long?

Tags: import, syntax, spss

I'm trying to read a data file into SPSS using `DATA LIST` but there are so many columns that the syntax line is too long;

```
NEW FILE.
DATA LIST LIST (" ") FILE = "C:\Projects\XXXXX study\Statistics\SPSS files\BIOF.DAT"
/ STUDY (A15) PT (F10) VISIT (F10) CPEVENT (A20) SUBEVE (F10) QUALIFYV (A70) LOCKFLAG (A1) REPEATSN (F3) DTE1 (DATE) WH (F3) WHC (A3) RSN (F3) RSNC (A50) SPEC (A200) NUM1 (F3) NUM2 (F3) 
NY1 (F3) NYC1 (A3) NY2 (F3) NYC2 (A3) NY3 (F3) NYC3 (A3) BANFF (F3) BANFFC (A15) NY4 (F3) NYC4 (A3) COMM (A200) DTE2 (DATE) LABV1 (F8,2) DTE3 (DATE) LABV2 (F8,2) NY5 (F3) NYC5 (A3) NUM3 (F3)
.
```

When I run this selection I get the following error:

> Error # 4163 in column 136. Text: )
>   The sequence of symbols used in specifying the format was not recognized.
>   Execution of this command stops.

If I understand correctly SPSS has a limit of 250 characters per line, is that correct?
When I remove everything after "NY1 (F3)" then it works correctly but then the columns NY1, NYC1, NY2 etc. are missing.
Any idea how to form a correct syntax for this? Or is there maybe an SPSS setting to allow for longer syntax lines?

(btw the `LIST (" ")` it's not visible here but it is the ESC character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with numeric variable formats defined with a comma in the syntax (e.g `(F8,2)`).
Syntax rules require a dot in the definition (should be `(F8.2)`. This holds true even when SPSS is set to display decimals with a comma in the data (e.g 54,4 instead of 54.4).

Comment: Thanks. Also, I still have to set `SET DECIMAL = COMMA.` to read the data correctly.Without it I get warnings `Warning # 1102 An invalid numeric field has been found` and values are changed to system-missing values.